# How to get DatePicker time to Calendar component and insert to Label component in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, date, calendar

I am new in this forum but it helped me a lot in coding.

Currently I am trying to code an iOS App as a time calculator in Swift (Xcode 11.2.1)

It should be able to pick a time from the DatePicker component and add 8 hours worktime to it. 
So the function is to display the time you can leave your workplace without getting negative in your flextime.

It should be displayed in the Label component.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    @IBAction func datePickerChanged(_ sender: Any) {

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short //show time in h:mm format

        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de-DE") //locale Germany

        let endTime = dateFormatter.date // declaring as date

        let calendar = Calendar.date(from: endTime) // get time from UIDatePicker

        let addHours = Calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 8, to: endTime) // add 8 hours

        let endTimeString = dateFormatter.string(from: endTime) //convert time from date to String

        dateLabel.text = endTimeString // show calculated time in UILabel
    }
}
```

I am getting 3 errors.

In the first let calendar line it says:

```
Instance member 'date' cannot be used on type 'Calendar'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?
```

In the following let addHours line I am getting the same error again, what is the point here?

The last error starts at the line when I am trying to convert the time from type date to String.

```
Cannot convert value of type '(String) -> Date?' to expected argument type 'Date'
```

Anyone could help me?

Comment: `Calendar` is the class but the methods you are calling are instance methods not class methods so you need an instance of `Calendar`. For simplicity use `Calendar.current`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
@IBAction func datePickerChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {

    var pickerDate = sender.date

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    guard let endDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 8, to: pickerDate) else { return }

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short //show time in h:mm format
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de-DE") //locale Germany
    var endTimeString = dateFormatter.string(from: endDate) //convert time from date to String
    dateLabel.text = endTimeString // show calculated time in UILabel

}
```

First, you need to get the selected date from the UIDatePicker.
Then, for date calulations, you need to specify a *calendar* to work with. Typically the *current*  calendar is what you want (this is the calendar specified for the device). Then, add 8 hours and convert it to a string.

Btw.: you need to keep in mind that when the user picks a date in the evening, there is a "day flip"  when you add 8 hours.

### Update

To add somthing like 8 hours and 13 minutes, it's best to use `DateComponents`:

```
var now = Date()
var calendar = Calendar.current
var addComp = DateComponents(calendar:calendar,
                             hour:8,
                             minute:13)

if let then = calendar.date(byAdding: addComp, to: now, wrappingComponents:false) {
    print(now)
    print(then!)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I wanted to code. Another question is how I can add 13 minutes to the 8 hours? I tried with adding .minute, value: 13, but it gives me still errors.

Comment: Is there another way? I want to have the output as an Label in the App-Screen, not in the console.

Comment: Just set the text of the label outlet, like before: `dateLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: then!)`

Comment: I understood it now..., but it doesn't keep refreshing the output anymore, like I choose 09:00 from DatePicker and changing it to 08:00, it still gives me the output from 09:00. What could I do here? With the old code it was refreshing it.

Comment: Check the code. Make sure you do not simply copy my code (like `var now = Date()`), but use the Date Pickers current value.

Comment: How would the code be in the case that the output keeps refreshing? Sorry but I am a big newbie in Swift and I understand nearly nothing.

Comment: When you change the date in he date picker, it will call your Action `datePickerChanged`. Here, you need to calculate the additional date and then set the `label.text` value. Try to set a breakpoint to `datePickerChanged` to see what happens.